# Read all available cookies: jQuery cookies

Tags: jquery, cookies, jquery-cookie

So I created this product called Office. You can create documents. These documents changes are applied and set by form data.

For Example, heres the [Document Editor](http://nsc-component.webs.com/Office/Editor/new-doc.html?)

Form data being, such as the name of the document would be ?docname=My Document

Now, on the home, there is a spot where you can get to documents you have saved. I thought it might be easy to create something where the link to the document is saved in a cookie or some sort of other storage system and then the user can access it on the home

Here is a link to the [Home](http://nsc-component.webs.com/Office/home.html?)

Someone suggested JQuery Cookies, I am sure I have gotten it set up to save the cookies depending on the naming the link the Document Name, and the value the link to the document, I just need a jQuery or Javascript code to display all of these cookies

On The [JQuery Cookies](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) web page on github, it says I can have it where it displays ALL JQuery Cookies that have been written, But the problem is  can't specify the cookie name and content because the user writes it. Can anyone show me how to use this? I hope it just displays all cookies.

Comment: Maybe it's obvious, but you can get only cookies from the same domain of the page/script...

Comment: `console.log()` it, just like you would any other object. `console.log($.cookie());`

Answer (score 1):

you can do

```
document.cookie.split(/; */).forEach(function(cookieraw){
  var cookie  = this.split('=');
  var name    = cookieraw[0];//print it 
  var value   = cookieraw[1]; //print it 
});
```

Comment: You already did an honest thing and worked with document.cookies. If you would consider refactoring that `.each` out to remove the jQuery dependency altogether that would be great

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum frankly,I did'nt get you.Have you noticed any wrong in the above lines ?

Comment: @Baadshah Are you sure you read it?[JQuery Cookies](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie#usage) Look at Read all available cookies:

Comment: Just a note @Baadshah, Benjamin was meaning doing something like this: http://pastebin.com/tehGcp0d, thus removing the dependency on jQuery completely.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Edited my post,as kevin clarified me.

Comment: Can you maybe see if you can write a code to write these cookies? and make the hyperlink the value

Answer (score 0):

> **You may use jquery.cookie.js**

then-

```
var all_cookies = $.cookie();
$.each(all_cookies, function (key, value) {
                console.log(key + ':' + value);
            });
```

Its works for me.